# Python one-line binary search

Tags: beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, reinventing-the-wheel, binary-search

```
import random

myNumbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 7)]
myNumbers.sort() #Binary search works on a sorted list.

print(myNumbers)

#How about this code:

binSearch = lambda anyList, item: anyList[int(len(anyList)/2)] \
if anyList[int(len(anyList)/2)] == item \ 
else None \ 
if int(len(anyList)/2) == 0 \
else binSearch(anyList[0:int(len(anyList)/2)], item) \ 
if anyList[int(len(anyList)/2)] > item \ 
else binSearch(anyList[int(len(anyList)/2):], item)

print(binSearch(myNumbers, 6))
```

Is it more or less elegant code? I'm beginner and I'm wondering if writing recursion in one line is a good practice.

Comment: I wouldn't say that writing _anything_ in one line is good practice if multiple lines would be clearer (and yes, here I would find a normal function much easier to read).

Comment: _Is it more or less elegant code?_ : After 10 months, have a look at that code again. The answer will be ...